# Node JS - Upload base 64 image to a picture library

Tags: picture-library, nodejs

I have been trying for a while to get this working; I have base64 in this format:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...
```

and i am trying to use REST to add it to the library, I am fully authenticated already, it's just the file is always corrupt when it gets to the library.